# Allow domain user in Plesk to run SVN Update

Tags: svn, plesk

On a LAMP/Plesk VPS, I would like to give one domain administrator the ability to SSH in to their accoount and run svn update.

It seems I have to give them the root password to do this, but this is not acceptable to me.

If I try with domain account, I get permission errors involving .svn/tmp/ files, which seem to have root permissions.

Has anyone else managed to set this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be that the checkout was created by the root user? Try deleting it and checking it out again as the domain user. The domain user should be able to update it without problems.

Comment: Another option instead of having to delete it and check it out again would be to `chown -R <domain_user>:<domain_user_group> /path/to/document/root`. That way it will change the owner of the files (including the .svn contents) to the domain user and give them permission to modify them, since some checkouts could be rather large.